# php page URL redirect htaccess php

Tags: .htaccess

Already read many Q&A but thats not work for me. please help as soon as possible.

Want to open this page
https://investmango.com/update/details.php?name=the-leela-sky-villa

in this url
https://investmango.com/update/the-leela-sky-villa

This code is not working for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/\d+)/$ https://investmango.com/update/$1 [L,R=302,QSA]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(\d+)$ details.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

One more thing where i have to add this code i mean in update folder or domain root directory

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess rules file. As its highly encouraged on SO; efforts should be there in question(s), thank you.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/\d+)/$ https://sample.com/update/$1 [L,R=302,QSA]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(\d+)$ details.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: I tried upper code but its not wokring

Comment: Thanks for sharing, please add these efforts in your question, thank you.

Comment: one more thing where i have to add i mean in update folder or the root directory

Comment: Thanks for sharing, please add these efforts in your question, thank you.

Comment: added please check

Comment: Thanks for doing so. So you are hitting https://sample.com/update/page-url url in browser?

Comment: yes but they open root index page html without css

Comment: OP has shown attempted code(after my initial comments) and added it in question. Not sure why close votes on question now.

Comment: "Want to open this page `https://sample.com/update/details.php?=page-url`" - Although you appear to be missing a URL parameter name? The regex `^[^/]+/(\d+)$` specifically matches digits only in the last path segment, so it will never match `/update/page-url` - unless `page-url` is really just a numeric ID? But then `name` is misleading. Where exactly are you putting this `.htaccess` file? With the current directives it will either not match the requested URL or will rewrite to the wrong URL, depending on where the `.htaccess` file is placed.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your htaccess rules file inside update folder and have it in following manner.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ $1/details.php?$2 [QSA,L]
```

***JS/CS rewrite/redirect:***
You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: Here my website check this is also not working
https://investmango.com/update/

after putting this code in .htaccess to update folder and hit project link
https://investmango.com/update/the-leela-sky-villa/

Comment: this is working link 
https://investmango.com/update/details.php?name=the-leela-sky-villa

Comment: they showing below screenshot 
https://i.postimg.cc/90TvGj8K/Screenshot-2021-12-17-173805.png

Comment: i hope you understand :-(

Comment: @DeepanshSagar, Sorry its not clear, could you please post more details where its not working?

Comment: Please check again I made the changes in question